# There is no reference field 'project_id' found for 'job.card.desc'

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have two modules and they are related each other but it shows an error There is no reference field found

please show me what I missed

my job.card.desc module looks like this:

```
class jobCardDesc(models.Model):

_inherit                =   'job.card.desc'
project_id          =   fields.Many2one('mrp.projects', string="Project ID")
```

and mrp.projects like this

```
class project_mrp(models.Model):
_name                   =   'mrp.projects'
name                    =   fields.Char(string = "Project Name")
code                    =   fields.Char(string = "Project Code", default = 'New')
jobCardIds              =   fields.One2many('job.card.desc','project_id',string="Job Card Ids")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working By adding

```
project_id          =   fields.Many2one('mrp.projects', string="Project ID")
```

directly in module **'job.card.desc'** , instead of adding **project_id** field in inheritted **job.card.desc** module